# Script program inputs in bash ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, input, data-entry

I'm in a course for C++ programming.

Our professor created a linux validation script against which our program output must match exactly.

It's running out of his own program and generates an output.txt file, then compares it against his output file, if it doesn't match it rejects the script.

The problem is, this program excepts probably 150-200 lines of input and if anything goes in wrong you have to start all over again. If you even enter an incorrect char, it must be restarted as the backspace registers as a character of its own.

How might I generate a bash script that would feed all of the input into the program automatically?

NOTE: We have to use his program as in: ~professor.name/submit asigname

Comment: Too broad. Need example of input/output or sample source code to narrow down what you need.

Comment: In addition, this is a frequently recurring question.  Look for duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How might I generate a bash script that would feed all of the input into the program automatically?

Without any example code or input/output, it is hard to gauge what precisely is that you need.

Otherwise, for a generic tool to automate interactive console programs, I would suggest to take a look at the [`Expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text file:

*answers.txt*

```
answer1
answer2
...
answerN
```

and use that as stdin for the program:

```
./your_program < answers.txt
```

Comment: We are using his program as:  ~professor.name/submit assigname

Comment: Is there a way I can force it to include the script?

Comment: Well I mean, your command ./your_program < answers.txt

Comment: His script is probably just grabbing the .cpp and .h files then compiling/running. Is there a way I can force it to include the command?

Comment: ?? Just `~professor.name/submit assigname < answers.txt`

Comment: It's saying that file is too shortor empty. Is there a special syntax for newline char? I tried asdf\n  the ouput was empty.

Comment: No, just press enter.

Comment: I don't think it is accepting it. Output is:

Submitter (V0.93 (Backspace allowed in script))
Submitting FP - Milestone 4
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -o ms4 ms4tester.cpp NonPerishable.cpp Perishable.cpp Date.cpp ErrorMessage.cpp Item.cpp 2> errms4.txt

Comment: ?? I don't get that. Probably your professor wants you to fill in the answers manually.... I'm AFK..

Comment: I think there is a conflict between the submitting program parameters and the < input.txt syntax